DACPAC Deploy is failing on one database but works fine for all others
Any reason why a dacpac deploy is failing to update certain database? It started failing out of nowhere and I tested the same dacpac on other databases and it works fine.
Usually I'd drop the tables that have the data loss occur or run-time errors and most often it'll allow the dacpac to deploy successfully. But it has been failing.
enter image description here
